# Cover a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, tiling, chessboard

Let $2n\times  2n $ board. I cover it with dominoes $1\times 2$ s.t. every cell is adjacent exactly one cell coverd by a domino. I have to find the maximal number of dominoes that can be placed in this way.

I think that the number is $\frac { n\cdot (n+1)}{2} $. I succeed for $n\in \lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace $ and I try to prove it by induction.

It's right my answer?

2 cells are adjacent  if they share a common side

Comment: What do you mean by "every cell is ad[j]acent exactly one cell cover[e]d by a domino"?

Comment: @Dr. Mathva I added this information

Comment: It may be easier to solve the problem by induction on a $2n\times2m$ board instead.

Comment: @P. Quinton It's my answer right?

Comment: I think that it's is problem 2 form EGMO 2019 (first contest was yesterday). See here https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t520112f6h1818715_yet_another_domino_problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show it is possible to place $n(n+1)/2$ dominoes, generalize the domino placements below.

[image]

To prove this is optimal, given a placement of dominoes, let

- $x$ be the number of interior dominoes,
- $y$ be the number of dominoes with both halves on the border,
- $z$ be the number of dominoes with one half on the border and the other in the interior.

Note that a perimeter domino covers $4$ perimeter squares, and a half-interior domino covers at least three perimeter squares. Since there are $4(2n-1)$ perimeter squares total, we must have
$$
4y+3z\le 4(2n-1).
$$
Furthermore, an interior domino covers $8$ squares, a border domino not on the corner covers $6$ squares, an a half-interior domino covers $7$ squares. There are at most $4$ corner dominoes, which each cover one fewer square. Therefore,
$$
8x+6y+7z\le 4n^2+4
$$
Putting this all together, we get
\begin{align}
x+y+z
&=\frac18(8x+6y+7z)+\frac1{16}(4y+7z)-\frac{5}{16}z
\\&\le \frac18(4n^2+4)+\frac1{16}(4(2n-1))
\\&= \frac12n(n+1)+\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
Finally, since $x+y+z$ is an integer, we further conclude that $$x+y+z\le \left\lfloor\frac12n(n+1)+\frac14\right\rfloor=\frac12n(n+1).$$